# How do I monitor the status of a program running in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, operating-system, monitoring

I know we look at the list of process with tasklist command.
However, what I would like to know is what happens within the process.

First part:
For example, I am running MS Word. 
So I click on "File" button. It will cause the drop down box to open. 
However, what happens in OS and is there anyway of monitoring this?
(Like a debugger or a log message to track the action that will show like
"MouseClicked Button File" and "Drop down opened")

Second part (If there is no solution to the first part):
As programmers we write programs in different languages like java, C/C++ and so on but all of them are compiled into .exe/.jar files. 
So I should be right to say that all of this compiled are readable by the OS so we should be able to write the program to create a software that will be able to do the above all of them are read by the OS.

Third Part: 
Please give me some tips to start working on this project that will show the status of a running program.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx